# Title of small press Space Colonization-Faring RPG

Tags: product-identification

Many years ago, c. 1995, I had a small press space colonization/faring/asteroid RPG I picked up mostly for the setting.

I can't recall the name of this title. So here are some clues:

1. Softcover, muted colors
2. Landscape format
3. B/W interiors
4. Large stations in Earth orbit and beyond *a la Outlander*
5. Asteroid mining and unions, again *a la Outlander*
6. Seems I recall Liz Danforth art
7. I **know** was advertised in *Dragon*, *Dungeon*, or *Challenge*, probably *Challenge* because it was one of the three I picked up regularly.

Any ideas? I'd know the title if it was mentioned I think.

Comment: I can't find anything likely in the RPGGeek database under [Liz Danforth's entry](http://rpggeek.com/rpgdesigner/13343/liz-danforth). If it's her art, she must not be credited, or it's a *really* obscure item.

Comment: That entry doesn't even have _Twilight:2000_ or ICE's Cyberpunk or Shadowrun. Whatever happened to the Pen and Paper DB after the "hacking"?

Comment: [Entry on RPG Geek](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/52126/high-colonies)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*High Colonies*?

> Two hundred years in the future, Earth is a deadly wasteland, ravaged by nuclear, chemical, and biological weapons. Humanity lives in exile, clinging to life on a multitude of space stations in the Solar System. These stations are the High Colonies, the last hope of mankind.

[image: The cover of High Colonies, showing a habitat and a lot of rocky debris floating above a blue-green planet.]

Comment: <barry-and-levon> _Awww Yeah_ </barry-and-levon>. Thanks @waynes-books. This was it. What's the format? I seem to recall it being in landscape, as noted, but maybe it was just smaller than standard books, e.g., most modules.

Comment: I feel like I've seen this cover art (from ads?) in landscape form. But the back cover pic of an actual book I have in my records is just white, with the usual promo text.

Answer (score 1):

This maybe wrong but I remember a friend having something close to what you are saying but most "Space" RPGs are somewhat like those.I did a search remembering terms he used to tell me and saw this:

Note: SFW non-spoiler link

http://www.waynesbooks.com/traveller.html

It had multiple sets/modules but as stated even with the detail you gave it seems a long shot to find since a lot of the space ones did similar setting and game play.

If its not then Good Luck and keep us updated.

Note: another idea is look in backlogs of the magazine if they have those up and searchable

Comment: It was not _Traveller_. :P I know what all the variations of _Traveller_ might be. Good resource though! I think Wayne's Books is in my circles on G+.